# Google Earth Pro Alternatives

Tags: dictionary, gis, shapefile

Is there any alternate free application like Google Earth Pro ? , My main thing is it should import shape files as a layer in the map.

Answer (score 0):

Depends upon what you are looking for.  If you really just want to see the shapefile, use something like qgis or udig.

If you want to see the shapefile on top of a street map or a satellite base layer, I am not sure there is something that will work for you out of the box.  Open Street Map has the data; a service like http://www.osm974.re/osm2gis/ can export a limited area of Open Street Map data as a shapefile.

You might want to peruse this page from the Open Street Map wiki: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Shapefiles

Comment: I am having my map data as shapefiles, I want to find the shortest path with directions using this shapefiles, Google Pro working fine but is not free, Is there any free apps on this ...

Comment: are you looking for shortest path along geoid, like this http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/scripts/geod-calc.html ?  It may help if you describe what you need to do instead of referring Google Earth Pro which I belive has many features.

Comment: Ooo, if by "with directions", you mean turn-by-turn street directions (e.g. "turn left in 4.5 km at Churchill Street"), that is harder.  There aren't many free sources for driving directions.  See http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Open_Source_Routing_Machine for one.

Answer (score 0):

There's this open source application called "Marble" that works ok...but unfortunately you can't load shapefiles into it. You have to convert your shapefiles into wkt with qgis or something before loading them in. The satellite imagery is so pathetic as to be considered nonexistent. But its faster than Google Earth Pro that's for sure, and you can use OpenStreetMap to get a pretty good vector scaled experience to see where you are.

http://marble.kde.org/index.php